# Ruby - substituting characters in a string with sequential elements of an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a string:

```
a = 'bla \n bla \n bla \n'
```

And an array:

```
b = ['1', '2', '3']
```

I want to search through the string, and replace every nth instance of \n with the (n-1)th element from the array, resulting in:

```
a = 'bla 1 bla 2 bla 3'
```

What is the simplest way for me to do this?

Comment: Are you trying every permutation of every possible question with the same structure but different objects?

Comment: While the topic was similar the given responses are completely different. Some people replying took the time to give answers, one of which has helped me greatly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`String#gsub` with a block makes short work of this:

```
a.gsub('\n') { b.shift }
```

Note that `Array#shift` modifies the original array. Make a copy of it first (`b.dup`) if that's a problem.

Comment: I thinking about it, nice!)

Answer (score 1):

You can use method [`sub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-sub)

```
a = 'bla \n bla \n bla \n'
b = ['1', '2', '3']
b.each { |i| a.sub!('\n', i) }
#> a
#=> "bla 1 bla 2 bla 3"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just one more way using `String#split` and `Array#zip`

```
a.split('\n').zip(b).join
#=> "bla 1 bla 2 bla 3"
```

Comment: It looks like the best answer to me. Short, to the point and non-destructive. Sorry, I'm all out of votes.